# General API security tips and info on how tokens work

Tags: mongodb, security, express, jwt, auth0

So I want to understand a little more about authentication in an API. I know very little about how security works.

I am using Auth0 for my app and it supports only logging in from a social media site. My API checks if a user is authenticated and checks data that is being sent to avoid wrong stuff to be saved in the database(mongodb). That is all I have currently implemented to secure my API. Is it possible that a user can take his own token that he got from logging in and post information to a different account by simply guessing a different user _id.

For example, an article receives all its content and the id of the article author.

If this is possible what are some solutions on securing my API.

Any other tips on making an API secure are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Auth0 supports logins with *anything* , not just social networks. You can login with username/passwords, LDAP servers, SAML servers, etc.

A token is a secure artifact. An author cannot change the id in a token without compromising the token itself (e.g. the digital signature will fail), so impersonating someone else is not that easy. The very first thing your API would need to do is checking the integrity of the token being added to the request, and reject any that contains an invalid one (bad signature, expired, etc).

It is a question that requires a lot of content, so I would recommend starting here: https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth

Comment: Thanks for the response. My question is if someone can use his own token to send data to the API on behalf of someone else through postman or anything similar just by changing the _id. My API takes the content of an article(title, content etc) and a field called author_id that I'm worried can be manipulated with.

Comment: Yes, if you loose the token, then anyone in possession of it can use it. Thats why all interactions should happen over SSL, and that's why tokens expire. So, in the chance the token is leaked, it cannot be used.

Comment: Unfortunately this still is not the answer I am looking for. I understand that if a token is lost, security can be breached. 

Imagine a simple mongodb schema for a user
user = {
_id: 123,
name: "whatever",
}
When a user creates an article this schema is used. 
article = {
id: 987
authorId: same as the user id
content: "blabla"
}
The article is retrieved through a GET request with the authorId. I am just curious if the user can change the authorId when making a POST request to the server to whatever he wants and send it to the database by using his own legit token.

Comment: not if the article is retrieved with authorid as a claim in the token. nobody, except the user with that authorid can send a (valid) token with someone else's id.